# What is this process, “usagetrackingagent”, and why is it showing under activity monitor on MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, activity-monitor

What is this process, “usagetrackingagent”, and why is it showing under activity monitor on MacBook?  Does anyone with Mojave or a MacBook in general have this process under activity monitor.  I quit the process and it hasn’t come back but was interested why it showed up in the first place. Thank you

Comment: Latest macOS Mojave, and it is there on my system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is running on my three Mojave laptops.

BSD System Manager's Manual                      USAGETRACKINGAGENT(8)

NAME

```
 UsageTrackingAgent -- Usage Tracking Agent
```

DESCRIPTION

```
 UsageTrackingAgent monitors and reports usage budgets set by Health, Parental Controls, or Device Management.
```

---

Obtained from: https://www.unix.com/man-page/mojave/8/UsageTrackingAgent/